# How to configure channel options in Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 SubscriberServiceApiClientBuilder

Tags: c#, google-cloud-pubsub

In Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 version 1.x.x, I was using PublisherServiceApiClient.Create and passing in "Channel" object, which was configured with target, credentials, and ChannelOptions. The ChannelOptions are grpc.max_receive_message_length and then grpc.max_send_message_length.

According to the documentation (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberServiceApiClient.html#Google_Cloud_PubSub_V1_SubscriberServiceApiClient_Create) you have to use SubscriberServiceApiClientBuilder (if you are not going to use default values: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberServiceApiClientBuilder.html).

SubscriberServiceApiClientBuilder allows you set ChannelCredentials, and Endpoint, but I don't see a way to set the ChannelOptions. How do I set the ChannelOptions in SubscriberServiceApiClientBuilder?

**Old code** for creating SubScriberServiceApiClient:

`SubscriberServiceApiClient.Create(channel); // channel is of type Channel`

**New code** for creating SubscriberServiceApiClient:

```
new SubscriberServiceApiClientBuilder
{
    ChannelCredentials = channelCredentials,
    Endpoint = endPoint,
}.Build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, `SubscriberServiceApiClient.Create()` has stopped accepting `grpccore::Channel` object. But you can still create a client by creating an underlying [`SubscriberServiceApiClientImpl`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1-2.3.0/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/SubscriberServiceApiClient.g.cs#L3164) object directly.

To elaborate more, `SubscriberServiceApiClientImpl` takes in a `Subscriber.SubscriberClient` object, that is derived from the `channel` variable (a `grpccore::Channel` object) that you wish to pass in. You can check the [old implementation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1-1.1.0/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/SubscriberServiceApiClient.cs#L927-L948) for how the `grpcClient` is created.

So in sum, your code may look like the following:

```
// Assuming `settings` (a `SubscriberServiceApiSettings` object) is
//     created (default to null)
// Assuming you’re created a `channel` object that is a `grpccore::Channel`
gax::GaxPreconditions.CheckNotNull(channel, nameof(channel));
grpccore::CallInvoker callInvoker = new grpccore::DefaultCallInvoker(channel);
gax::GaxPreconditions.CheckNotNull(callInvoker, nameof(callInvoker));
grpccore::Interceptors.Interceptor interceptor = settings?.Interceptor;
if (interceptor != null) {
    callInvoker = grpccore::Interceptors.CallInvokerExtensions.Intercept(
        callInvoker, interceptor);
}
Subscriber.SubscriberClient grpcClient = new Subscriber.SubscriberClient(callInvoker);
SubscriberServiceApiClient client = new SubscriberServiceApiClientImpl(
    grpcClient, settings);
```